# Proof of set is a subset of another set?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

```
Prove      {5^(6n+2) : n ∈ Z} ⊆ {125^m/5 : m ∈ Z}
```

I have worked out doesn't look correct?

```
I have done it by taking 125^m/5   ->  5^(6n+2)/5
```

Comment: That's not a proof. Show us your steps. You can't just say "I took _ to _" - that isn't saying anything.

Comment: What do you think $125^{m/5}\implies 5^{(6n+2)/5}$ means?  That seems like saying $275z\implies 3.145^2$.  It doesn't make any sense.  Neither of those are statements so they can't imply anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$5^{6n+2}=5^{6n+3-1}=\frac{5^{3(2n+1)}}{5}$$